# Using values of dictionary(of lists) as arguments for iterative functions

Tags: python, dictionary

Imagine we have a dictionary

```
views_params = {"list_a": [1,2,3], "list_b": [1,2,8]}
```

I do want to iterate in each list of values by key using the following function:

```
def function_with_listed_arguments(k, y, z):
    w = k + y + 2*z
    return w
```

I tried using a dictionary comprehension to get key:value pairs:

```
dictionary_list = {
    k: function_with_listed_arguments(v) for k,v in views_params
}
final_result = [dictionary_list.values()]
print(final_result)
```

The final result should be `[9,19]`

However, I am getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` in the dictionary comprehension. Anybody can point me to what am I doing wrong?

Tried with `**kwargs` still no results.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you want `final_result = list(dictionary_list.values())`.

Comment: This one works as well `final_result = [*dictionary_list.values()]`. Thanks! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there!
You only needed `items()` on the dict and a list decomposition when passing the params.

```
views_params = { "list_a": [1,2,3], "list_b": [1,2,8],}

def function_with_listed_arguments(k,y,z):
  w = k + y + 2*z
  return w

dictionary_list = {
    k: function_with_listed_arguments(*v) for k,v in views_params.items()
}
final_result = [dictionary_list.values()]
print(final_result)
```

Outcome:

```
[dict_values([9, 19])]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Tried items but no unpacking, vice-versa but not both! Thanks!